# Verify that the given sequence is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**
Verify that the sequence {$f_n$} , where $f_n= n \sin( 4 \pi^2 n^2+x^2)^ {0.5}$ , converges uniformly on$ [0,a] , a \geq 0 $. Does {$f_n$} converge uniformly on  $\mathbb{R} $?

**Attempt**
I have figured out that the the given function converges pointwise to $f(x) = x^2/4\pi$. After that i don't know how to proceed. My approach is to find $d_n$=sup {$ f_n(x) - f(x)| x \in [0,a] $}. Then show that $d_n$ approaches zero as n tends to infinity. But i am not able to find $d_n$

Edit:  $\sin( 4 \pi^2 n^2 +x^2)^ {0.5} $= $\sin ( 2n\pi( 1+ \frac{x^2}{4 \pi^2 n^2})^{0.5} + 2n\pi- 2n \pi)$=
$ \sin ( 2n\pi( 1+ \frac{x^2}{4 \pi^2 n^2})^{0.5} -1)$=
$ \sin (\frac{ x^2} { (4n^2 \pi^2+x^2 )^{0.5}+ 2n\pi})$
Now it is easy to see how pointwise limit should be $\frac{x^2}{4\pi}$

Comment: While I agree with your assessment of the potential approach, it's hard to know how to describe that approach without seeing how you proved that the pointwise limit is $x^2/4\pi$. It's likely that a slightly more careful version of that proof will succeed in establishing the uniform convergence on $[0,a]$.

Comment: Edited to question  . Thanks .

Comment: Your edit seems wrong, where did that $ -1$ come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you realized, the term $(4\pi^2n^2+x^2)^{0.5}$ will, for fixed $x$ and increasing $n$, get very near to $2\pi n$, so the sin function will apply to a small value $(4\pi^2n^2+x^2)^{0.5}-2\pi n$ that can be easily approximated by the Taylor series for the sin-function.

The problem is therefore to put this into quantifiable inequalites that can finally be used to prove the uniform convergence.

First for small $\epsilon > 0$ (say $\epsilon < 1$) we have

$$1+\frac{\epsilon}2-\epsilon^2 < \sqrt{1+\epsilon} < 1+\frac{\epsilon}2,$$

which can proved by squaring both sides of each inequality. The right inequality is always true, the left side, when squared is $1+\epsilon$ + terms of $\epsilon$ of order $2$ or greater and the coefficient of $\epsilon^2$ is negative.

That means, because

$$(4\pi^2n^2+x^2)^{0.5}=2\pi n\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2 n^2}},$$

and if we set $x_n:=\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2 n^2}$, we get for $x_n < 1$

$$2\pi n(1+\frac{x_n}2-{x_n}^2) < (4\pi^2n^2+x^2)^{0.5} < 2\pi n(1+\frac{x_n}2).$$

If we assume the even stricter inequality $2nx_n < 1$, we get

$$2\pi n < 2\pi n(1+\frac{x_n}2-{x_n}^2) < (4\pi^2n^2+x^2)^{0.5} < 2\pi n(1+\frac{x_n}2) < 2\pi n +\pi\frac12.$$

Since the sin-function is increasing in the interval $[2\pi n,2\pi n+\frac12\pi]$, and $2\pi$-periodic, we get

$$\sin (2\pi n(\frac{x_n}2-{x_n}^2)) < \sin ((4\pi^2n^2+x^2)^{0.5}) < \sin (2\pi n\frac{x_n}2),$$

under the assumption $2nx_n < 1$, which is equivalent to $x^2 < 2\pi^2 n$.

Putting in the definition of $x_n$, we get

$$\sin (\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}-2\pi n{x_n}^2) < \sin ((4\pi^2n^2+x^2)^{0.5}) < \sin (\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}).$$

---

Let's for a moment stop here and wonder if the assumptions I made are reasonable.

The most strict assumption I made is $2nx_n < 1$, which is equivalent to $x^2 < 2\pi^2 n$. In case where we consider the interval $[0,a]$ for $x$, this is fullfilled if $n > \frac{a^2}{2\pi^2}$. Since uniform convergence requires bounds for some $n>M$, increasing $n$ is not a problem. That means that we can make the term $x_n$ as small as later required, and this is uniformly over the interval [0,a].

---

Going back to the inequality above, we use  $\sin(x) < x$ on the right side and $x-\frac{x^3}6 < \sin(x)$ on the left hand side to get

$$(\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}-2\pi n{x_n}^2) - \frac{(\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}-2\pi n{x_n}^2)^3}6 < \sin ((4\pi^2n^2+x^2)^{0.5}) < \frac{x^2}{4\pi n}.$$

Multiplying that with $n$ leads to the final inequality:

$$(\frac{x^2}{4\pi}-2\pi n^2{x_n}^2) - \frac{n(\frac{x^2}{4\pi n}-2\pi n{x_n}^2)^3}6 < n\sin ((4\pi^2n^2+x^2)^{0.5}) < \frac{x^2}{4\pi}.$$

Notice term on both sides without $n$ is the $\frac{x^2}{4\pi}$. The remaining terms (on the left side) are of much smaller order. Recall that $x_n=\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2 n^2}$, that means

$$2\pi n^2{x_n}^2 = 2\pi n^2\frac{x^4}{16\pi^4 n^4}= \frac{x^4}{8\pi^3 n^2},$$

which means the term becomes uniformly small when $\frac{a^4}{8\pi^3 n^2}$ is made small by a big $n$. The remaining term has an even smaller order and become uniformely small when $n$ gets big.

This means that $f_n(x)$ on the interval $[0,a]$ is squeezed between $\frac{x^2}{4\pi}$ and a sligher smaller term whose difference to $\frac{x^2}{4\pi}$ can be made uniformely as small as required. That means $f_n(x)$ uniformely converges to $\frac{x^2}{4\pi}$ on any finite interval $[0,a]$.

---

If we consider the whole line $\mathbb R$ for convergence, the matter changes. No matter how big we choose $n$, there will always be big values of $x$ where $(4\pi^2n^2+x^2)^{0.5}$ is far from $2\pi n$ and thus all the previous discussion becomes useless.

For example, we can choose $x(n)=\sqrt{5}\pi n$, which means

$$(4\pi^2n^2+x(n)^2)^{0.5} = (4\pi^2n^2+5\pi^2n^2)^{0.5}= (9\pi^2n^2)^{0.5}=3\pi n$$

which implies

$$f_n(x(n))=n\sin((4\pi^2n^2+x(n)^2)^{0.5})=n\sin(3\pi n)=0$$

That means for any $n>0$ we can use that $x(n)$ to show that

$$|f_n(x(n)) - \frac{x(n)^2}{4\pi}|=\frac{x(n)^2}{4\pi} = \frac{5\pi^2n^2}{4\pi}=5\pi n^2$$

which is not something that goes to zero for $n \to \infty$. So the convergence of $f_n(x)$ is **not** uniform on $\mathbb R$.